# Primeng list-box check boxes checked or options selected

Tags: angular, listbox, primeng

I am using Primeng with Angular 7. I am facing problem in showing already selected checkbox checked.

Below I'm showing the listbox but checkboxes are not checked. Can anybody help me with it? What am I missing?

I am using p-listbox under p-dialog

```
<p-dialog
    header="Assign Feature"
    [(visible)]="displayDialog"
    [responsive]="true"
    showEffect="fade"
    [modal]="true"
    [draggable]="true"
    [responsive]="true"
    [contentStyle]="{ 'max-height': '320px', 'max-width': '400px' }"
    [positionTop]="100"
>
    <p-listbox
        [options]="sourcelist"
        multiple="multiple"
        checkbox="checkbox"
        filter="filter"
        optionLabel="name"
        [(ngModel)]="selectedPermission"
        [listStyle]="{ 'max-height': '200px' }"
    ></p-listbox>

    <p>
        Selected Permissions:
        <span
            *ngFor="let c of selectedPermission"
            style="margin-right: 10px"
            >{{ c.name }}</span
        >
    </p>
</p-dialog>
```

Please refer to the screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In selected items, You have to pass whole object not single string for making checkbox selected.

### html

```
<p-listbox
    [options]="sourcelist"
    multiple="multiple"
    checkbox="checkbox"
    filter="filter"
    optionLabel="name"
    [(ngModel)]="selectedPermission"
    [listStyle]="{ 'max-height': '200px' }"
    ></p-listbox>

{{selectedPermission | json}}
```

### ts

```
export class AppComponent {
    sourcelist = [
        { name: 'Update', value: { id: 1, name: 'Uodate'} },
        { name: 'Delete', value: { id: 2, name: 'Delete'} },
        { name: 'Show', value: { id: 3, name: 'Show' } }
    ];

    selectedPermission = [];

    constructor() {
        this.selectedPermission.push(this.sourcelist[1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am already using object for sourceList and selectedPermission both. I think there is some issues with ID mapping.  Just Let me confirm '1' is id  that you passed to this.sourceList. What If I have to pass an array of Ids through it . As I am getting multiple type errors for same. My type for sourcelist is  sourcelist: SelectItem[];

Comment: I am setting the second item as selected from array

Comment: Can I make it selected with 'id' inside value object somehow?

Comment: Yes you can for example if you data from server like [1,3,5] then you will loop from data and push it in selectedItem variable